# How can I use a variable on BigQuery SQL Editor?

Tags: google-bigquery

While writing SQL queries on BigQuery UI, sometimes I do a lot of `JOIN` over multiple tables using many `WHERE` clauses with the same `date` condition for each table. 
Whenever I need to see the results for a different date, I have to replace it at multiple locations in the query. I wonder if there is a simple way to use a variable in the BQ SQL Editor and pass it just once (top/bottom)?

This is true for all the complicated queries as we have to search throughout the query for variables to change.

Answer (score 4):

While [parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#console) are not available in the Console. You can use [Scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting), instead.

According to your need, you can use [DECLARE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare) and/or [SET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#set). It is stated in the documentation that:

> ***DECLARE***: Declares a variable of the specified type. If the DEFAULT clause is specified, the variable is initialised with the
>   value of the expression; if no DEFAULT clause is present, the variable
>   is initialised with the value NULL

The syntax is as follows:

```
#Declaring the variable's type and initialising the variable using DEFAULT
DECLARE variable STRING DEFAULT 'San Francisco';

SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_bikeshare.bikeshare_regions` 
#using the variable inside the where clause
WHERE name = variable
```

> ***SET:*** Sets a variable to have the value of the provided expression, or sets multiple variables at the same time based on the
>   result of multiple expressions.

And the syntax, as below:

```
#Declaring the variable using Declare and its type
DECLARE variable STRING;
#Initialising the variable
SET variable = 'San Francisco';

SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_bikeshare.bikeshare_regions` 
#using the variable inside the where clause
WHERE name = variable
```

In both examples above, I have queried against a public dataset `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_bikeshare.bikeshare_regions`. Also, both outputs are the same,

```
Row region_id   name    
1   3           San Francisco
```

In addition to the above example, more specifically to your case, when declaring a variable as date you can to it as follows:

```
DECLARE data1 DATE DEFAULT DATE(2019,02,15);


WITH sample AS(
SELECT DATE(2019,02,15) AS date_s, "Some other field!" AS string UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2019,02,16) AS date_s, "Some other field!" AS string UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2019,02,17) AS date_s, "Some other field!" AS string UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(2019,02,18) AS date_s, "Some other field!" AS string 
)
SELECT * FROM sample
WHERE date_s = data1
```

And the output,

```
Row    date_s       string1
1      2019-02-15   Some other field!
```

Comment: @loadbox, was it helpful for you?